# Camellia Ruby Computer Vision Library on OS X

Tags: ruby, image-processing, computer-vision

Has anyone had any luck getting the [Camellia](http://camellia.sourceforge.net/) computer vision library to install on OS X? I've been banging my head against a wall trying to get it to install. There is [only one reference I can find](http://po-ru.com/diary/camellia-and-ruby-on-mac-os-x/) online and it is a bit dated. I've followed the instructions to the T with no luck.

I'm hoping one of your brilliant folks on SO can help a dude out.

Answer (score 2):

What exactly is your problem? Is there any error message? Are you trying to compile the library or are you trying to build the gem?

The sourcecode of the Camellia library is written in C. If you want to compile the library on your OS X machine you'll need a C [compiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler) (like [GCC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_Collection)). The easiest way to get one on OS X is by installing [Apple's XCode](http://developer.apple.com/TOOLS/xcode/) because GCC is part of this package. You can check if you've GCC installed by entering the command **`which gcc`** in a [Terminal](http://www.osxterminal.com/) window. If this command returns the path to the gcc application (like **`/usr/bin/gcc`**) you already have installed GCC. If the command returns nothing, you should install GCC (or XCode, as mentioned before).

After that, just follow the steps on the website you mentioned.

If that doesn't answer your question, please edit your request and be more specific about the problems and what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to run on Leopard with the following steps (already have Ruby, etc., set up - install XCode from the OS X installation DVD if you don't already have it):

1. Downloaded the Unix/Linux distribution (CamelliaLib-2.7.0.tar.gz)
2. Opened up the tarball
3. `cd CamelliaLib-2.7.0/`
4. `./configure`
5. `sudo make`
6. `sudo make install`

Cool, so that's Camellia installed. Next up for the Ruby part.

First, I looked for the gem with `gem search -r camellia`:

```
*** REMOTE GEMS ***

camellia (2.7.0)
camellia-rb (1.2)
```

Nice, so all it should take is a simple `gem install`.

```
$ sudo gem install camellia
ERROR:  could not find gem camellia locally or in a repository
```

Weird. Anyway, I installed the other gem:

```
$ sudo gem install camellia-rb
```

And sure enough (you'll need to use `require 'rubygems'` first unless you've got a different setup like me):

```
$ irb
irb(main):001:0> require 'camellia'
=> true
```

Hope that gets you started.

Answer (score 0):

Not good !!!

```
sudo gem install camellia-rb
```

is NOT the camellia graphics gem, it is a cypher gem, so still no good solution

the problem is getting the camellia graphics gem into os X leopard working, anyone else??

Answer (score 0):

- Download CamelliaLib-2.7.0.tar.gz
- tar xf CamelliaLib-2.7.0.tar.gz
- cd CamelliaLib-2.7.0
- ./configure
- make
- sudo make install
- cd ..
- Download camellia-2.7.0-x86-linux.gem from rubyforge
- mkdir camellia-gem
- cd camellia-gem
- tar xvf ../camellia-2.7.0-x86-linux.gem
- tar zxvf data.tar.gz
- cd ext
- modify extconf.rb as described

```
 CONFIG['LDSHARED'] = "g++ -shared -lCamellia"
 to
 CONFIG['LDSHARED'] = "g++ -lCamellia -bundle -flat_namespace -undefined suppress"
```

- ruby extconf.rb
- if you have the default leopard install of ruby, modify topdir in the Makefile to

```
topdir = /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/universal-darwin9.0
```

- remove "-Wl,-export-dynamic" from DLDFLAGS and "-Wl,-R'$(libdir)'" from LIBPATH
- make sure that arch, sitearch and ruby are correct
- remove -lcrypt from LIBS

```
arch = universal-darwin9.0
sitearch = universal-darwin9.0
ruby = /usr/bin/ruby
```

- make sure LDSHARED change took in Makefile

```
LDSHARED = g++ -lCamellia -bundle -flat_namespace -undefined suppress
```

- .so to .bundle for DLLIB

```
DLLIB = $(TARGET).bundle
```

- make
- sudo cp camellia.bundle /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/universal-darwin9.0